# Is this use of "ecumenical" correct/standard?

Tags: meaning

Mokyr ([2022](https://eh.net/book_reviews/how-the-world-became-rich-the-historical-origins-of-economic-growth/)):

> Rubin and Koyama present balanced and fair surveys of made in the literature, but they are reluctant to take strong positions. Such an ecumenical approach sets them apart from Clark’s *Farewell to Alms* and McCloskey’s *Bourgeois Dignity*, where the authors take up similar issues but in a much stronger opinionated mode.

From the above sentences, I would interpret "ecumenical" to mean "balanced, fair, unopinionated". (Perhaps my interpretation is wrong--if so, explain why.)

Is this use of "ecumenical" correct/standard? It does not seem to match the definitions or examples I've found on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ecumenical), [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecumenical), [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ecumenical), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ecumenical).

Comment: It seems to be a metaphorical use, meaning that they concentrate on what unites the different shades of opinion rather than what divides them.

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives "2. worldwide or general in extent, influence, or application". It's being used here to mean general, universal, wide-ranging, considering all the different points of view, much as the dictionary says. Collins says the sense "universal; general; worldwide" is rare, but I think it's more common than they think.

Comment: [Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ecumenical) includes the broadened << **ecumenical** [adjective]:  unifying, ...] >>.  So non-controversial, which almost always signifies 'avoiding all pronouncements that might lead to controversy' (which gets very close to 'sitting on the fence'). Sticking to the facts (just presenting the data, without projections). // I won't present this as an 'answer', as I'd put 'but this is a difficult-to-find and hardly convincing reference, even though I do agree with it' as a comment if I saw it as an answer here.

Comment: Maybe the writer meant _equanimical_ (in the sense of balanced or impartial). The OED gives the adjective form of _equaninimity_ as _equanimous_, but a [Google Books search for _equanimical_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22equanimical%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsbzvmOiYLTYhQ6hsubroF8DWHghsA%3A1671228370519&ei=0uucY_moH9HZ9APDs73YDQ&ved=0ahUKEwj52fPqkv_7AhXRLH0KHcNZD9sQ4dUDCAg&oq=%22equanimical%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAwyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6BQgAEIAEOgUIABCiBFC8CVioMGCuVWgAcAB4AIABTogB7QKSAQE1mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) yields 54 unique matches.

Comment: ... Those matches range in publication date from an 1853 instance in _Ainsworth's Magazine_ ("I spent the evening with Ernest in my _salon_, not with the most **equanimical** feelings, I must own") to a 2020 instance in a book of essays ("In that month, you had been quieter and more **equanimical**").

Comment: What is meant by "Rubin and Koyama present balanced and fair surveys of made in the literature"?

Answer (score 1):

The term "ecumenical" is mostly used in regards to church matters: if i.e. a mass is organized so that different christian denominations (lutherans, catholics, ....) can attend, it is called an "ecumenical mass".

The origin of the word is ancient greek ("ἡ οἰκουμένη", from "οἰκέω", to inhabit, "the inhabited [earth]") and means soemthing even people of different opinions/denominations (like different christian sects, who nominally think of each other as heretics or heathens) can share with.

So, "fair" or "unbalanced" is perhaps a part of it, but also connoted is "avoiding all points of contention". Summing up, the meaning is best phrased - as @jsw29 noticed in his comment - as **acceptable to everyone**.

A probable synonym could be "inclusive".

Comment: I thought i had made that cleat enough. Anyways, i edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, but it's no more "cleat" than "surveys of made in the literature".